# htaccess 301 redirects for some URLs of acquired company site

Tags: wordpress, apache, .htaccess, redirect, mod-rewrite

I want to move some content from a website of a company we just acquired (company b) to my company's website (company a) and redirect those links from b to a. Easy enough, but I want to get rid of everything else that I am not moving over to company a. There are 950 total pages and I am using 150 of those. If I set up my htaccess file with the 150 redirects for the content I want, then have the last redirect in the `.htaccess`:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks
RewriteEngine on
RewriteRule (.*) http://www.newdomain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Would that redirect everything that I didn't set up with a redirect to the home page of my company site?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Would that redirect everything that I didn't set up with a redirect to the home page of my company site?

Yes, providing you have used mod_rewrite `RewriteRule` redirects for the other redirects and not mod_alias `Redirect` (or `RedirectMatch`). However, there is no need to capture the URL-path in the `RewriteRule` *pattern*, ie. change `(.*)` to `.*` or simply `^` to match everything.

You should test with 302 (temporary) redirects to avoid caching issues should you make a mistake. 301 (permanent) redirects are cached persistently by the browser - including any errors.

You've tagged your question "WordPress". All these redirects need to go before the WordPress front-controller, at the top of the config file.

> I want to get rid of everything else

However, if you want to "get rid of everything else" then consider serving a 404 (or 410 Gone) instead of mass redirecting to the homepage (which will likely be seen as a "soft-404" anyway in terms of SEO). For example:

```
RewriteRule ^ - [R=404]
```

or

```
RewriteRule ^ - [G]
```

To send a 410 response. The `L` flag is not required in this instance.

Comment: In the mass redirect at the end, I thought about redirecting the home page of company b to the press release on our site (company a) that details the acquisition, or to the solutions page for their products on our site. Then I could implement the 404 or 410 for all the other pages.

Comment: (Is that a statement or a question?) "redirecting the home page of company b to the press release on our site (company a)" - That wouldn't be part of the "mass redirect" at the end. Redirecting just the "home page" is a specific redirect, that should go before this.